# Search a string using list elements for matches and return the match found

Tags: python

I am trying to search a string for any elements in a list, and return the match found.

I currently have

```
y = "test string"
z = ["test", "banana", "example"]

if any(x in y for x in z):
   match_found = x
   print("Match: " + match_found)
```

This obviously does not work, but is there a good way to accomplish this besides using a for loop and an if loop?

Comment: Are you matching against all of *y* or just the words within it? For example, given *y = "testXstring"* what output would you expect? Also, Python does not have the concept of an *if loop*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you looking for this

```
text = "test string"
words = ["test", "banana", "example"]

found_words = [word for word in words if word in text]
print(found_words)
```

result

```
['test']
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you should do:

```
res = [x for x in z if x in y]
print(f"Match: {', '.join(res) if res else 'no'}")

# Output
Match: test
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do the below:

```
y = "test string"
z = ["test", "banana", "example"]

for x in z:
 if x in y:
  match_found = x
  print("Match: " + match_found)
  break
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use filter and lambda function:

```
>>> list(filter(lambda x: x in y, z))
['test']
```